# CodeIgniter + Smarty = Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, codeigniter-2

Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded and unzipped CI
2. Downloaded and unzipped Smarty in `/application/libraries/Smarty-3.1.4`
3. Saved `https://github.com/kzhiwei/codeigniter-smarty/blob/master/application/libraries/Smartylib.php` to `/application/libraries/Smartylib.php` (also fixed line 2 to point to the correct folder)
4. Added `Smartylib` in autoload libraries
5. Created a `test.tpl` and called it from the controller: `$this->Smartylib->display('test.tpl');`

Now, I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function createTemplate() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\myapp\application\libraries\Smarty-3.1.4\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 47
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Library references](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html) are case sensitive:

```
$this->load->library('smartylib');
$this->smartylib->display('test.tpl');
```

Comment: Thanks! You are welcome to fork the project: https://github.com/kzhiwei/codeigniter-smarty